# Search Disallow: / in robots.txt

Tags: php, regex, robots.txt

I want to search **`Disallow: /`** in robots.txt of domains.
I have wrote regex, but it is not working.

```
if(preg_match("!Disallow:\s*/\s\r\n!i",$string,$disallow_char))
{
  print_r($disallow_char);
}
```

Following are two test cases.
1)

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /
```

2)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /product/generate_pdf/40
Disallow: /news/
Disallow: /news/bollards
Disallow: /product/generate_pdf/44
Disallow: /
Disallow: /page_management/insert
Disallow: /glossary/ajax_call/update_words
```

It should output true for both the cases.

Comment: `preg_match()` returns `true` or `false`, depending if it matched or not. If it doesn't match, it can't print anything.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, I already mentioned my regex is not working. I want a regex which is true for both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assert that either a newline sequence or the end of the string follows:

```
echo preg_match('~Disallow:\h*/(?:\R|$)~i', $string)
```

**Explanation**:

```
Disallow:      # 'Disallow:'
\h*            # horizontal whitespace (0 or more times)
/              # '/'
(?:            # group, but do not capture:
  \R           #   '\R' (any Unicode newline sequence) 
 |             #  OR
  $            #   before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)              # end of grouping
```

Comment: could you pls explain it.